# Java: class with exchangeable fields?

Tags: java

I have a simple class:

```
public class MailAttachment {

    InputStream inputStream;    //file to send as an attachment
    String fileName;            //name given to the sent file as an attachment
}
```

I use this class for sending emails like that:

```
public boolean sendEmailWithAttachments(String[] recipients, MailAttachment[] attachments, String subject, String body) {
    ...
}
```

I also have method for retrieving attachment (file) from any message on the server:

```
public File retrieveFile(String filename, boolean shouldDeleteFromServer) {
    /* returns retrieved file */
}
```

But I'd like to make 'retrieveFile' method also return back object of type 'MailAttachment' but with different fields which I need:

```
public class MailAttachment {

    File file;  //file retrived from mail server, existing on disk
    String mailSubject; //The name of the message (subject) that holds the attachment
}
```

How to implement this so that the send method and the retrieve method use the same type which is 'MailAttachment'? 
I thought about inheritance and also about that this type 'MailAttachment' had all these fields.
What is the best smart way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the original `MailAttachment` class with `InputStream` in both cases to pass back file information.

Set `inputStream` to an instance of `FileInputStream` constructed with a `File` argument ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.io.File))).

Comment: Yes, this is simple and obvious and I don't even need `fileName` field because can get it from `File` object thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you have comes from a flaw in the design of the `MailAttachment` class from an object-oriented perspective. This class mixes *I/O* constructs and *business domain* content. It is not clear to me what are the semantic, role and responsibility associated to a `MailAttachment`:

- Should it be a pure *value* object, *i.e.* a mere data container with no responsibility to process this data or interact with it?
- Is the data "stored" by a `MailAttachment` object subject to changes over time? Should the content of a `MailAttachment` object be allowed to be updated, or should another `MailAttachment` object be created if the data it represents changes?
- When should the data of a `MailAttachment` be *loaded*? Is it simpler to segregate responsibilities and separate loading the data (e.g. from a file system or a TCP socket) from its representation?

  - When and how is the `InputStream` consumed in the first version of `MailAttachment`?
  - When and how is the `File` read in the second version of `MailAttachment`?
  - What is the meaning of `fileName` in the first version of `MailAttachment`? Is it the name of a file to which is associated the `InputStream`? Is it the name of the file to be created for the recipent? Is it both? Is it a simple file name or does it include a path?

These questions -and many more- could help you to build a consistent abstraction for what you want to be a `MailAttachment`. It could lead for instance to immutable data objects of this type:

```
public final class MailAttachment {
  private final String subject;
  private final String content;
  private final String fileName;
  ...
}
```

While the construction of these objects is encapsulated in a dedicated class which responsibility is to build `MailAttachment`:

```
public final class MailAttachmentFactory {

  public MailAttachment create(File file) {
    return create(new FileInputStream(file));
  }

  public MailAttachment create(InputStream is) {
    // consume stream, check content, handle errors...
  }
```

Thereby providing you with an object which is agnostic of how its data has been loaded or downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

**You can use generics to accomplish that:**

```
public class MailAttachment<T,A> {
    private T stream;
    private A name;

    public T getStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    public void setStream(T stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public A getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(A name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

*Example:*

```
MailAttachment<InputStream, String> obj = new MailAttachment<InputStream, String>();

MailAttachment<File, String> obj = new MailAttachment<File, String>();
```

**Hope this helps!**